# SQL query not showing columns in DataSet in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio, dataset

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008. I declare an `@query` param via `DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)`, I then set this `@query` according to the type of data sent in and then I use `exec [sys].[sp_executesql] @query` to execute the stored procedure.

The problem I'm having is that I'm using a DataSet in Visual Studio, that links to this stored procedure (used on a report).

When I do my stored procedure in this manner (with the `@query`), then the dataset does not pick up the column data to show. I had to create the stored procedure this way (with `@query`), because I need the where clause to be different depending on the data sent in.

My code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_Test_GetFooData]
    @pName VARCHAR(250) = '',
    @pID INT = NULL
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

        SET @query = 'SELECT FOO.FirstName, FOO.LastName
                FROM Test.FooOne AS FOO'

        IF ( @pName = '--- SELECT ---' ) 
            BEGIN
                SET @query = @query + ' WHERE FOO.ID = '
                    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @pID) + ''
            END
        ELSE 
            BEGIN
                SET @query = @query + ' WHERE FOO.ID = '
                    + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @pID) + ' AND
                                            PP.FirstName + LIKE ''%' + @pName
                    + '%'' '
            END
        EXEC [sys].[sp_executesql] @query           
    END
```

I have tested the query and it returns the correct data when I run the stored procedure. When I don't use `SET @query = 'SELECT STATEMENT' EXEC @query` then the dataset works as it should.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The dataset isn't able to determine what the columns are because they could be different. Even though you are setting the columns to be returned and not changing them, the possibility is there for you to. Therefore the dataset won't set any columns. You could add these manually.

Comment: This query can't work right. There is a syntax error in the query. Please paste the query as is here again....

Comment: `--- Select`. Here the two dashes are marking the line as comment, so it would ignore the closing quote (`'`) and a syntax error would occur...

Comment: I edited my original stored procedure to an example stored procedure. But I fixed my problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to write the query in a different way eg.

```
SELECT FOO.FirstName,      
       FOO.LastName               
FROM Test.FooOne AS FOO
WHERE FOO.ID = @pID 
and PP.FirstName LIKE case when @pName = '--- Select ---' then PP.FirstName else '%' + @pName + '%' end
```

This will always compare Foo.ID to @pID
and will either compare pp.FirstName to itself (always returning true) or wil